# How to imitate watercolor-esc imperfections and tranparencies in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How can you create watercolor-esc transparencies, varying levels of depth of color and also creating imperfections, like these two images bellow? (both by [Elisa Webler](http://www.elisawerbler.com))

I've tried taking a vector drawing, adding transparency to the shapes and adding noise over the top, but it doesn't get the same look, it looks much flatter.

I've put a basic drawing similar to the ones bellow in a .ai file in [MY DROPBOX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9a1n9f6kticsrf/shapes-for-experiment.ai) - if anyone wants them to experiment with filters, effects etc.

[image: elisa webler] 
[image]

Comment: You're comparing a silkscreened print with vector application artwork. There's no substitute for canvas texture, ink distribution, and screen bumping. Any attempt will always appear flat because of the nature of software. You'll have to manually create uneven textures, uneven color fills, and screen bumps.

Answer (score 2):

So I think your best bet is to grab a watercolor paper texture from Google images or a stock photo site. Make that your bottom later and lock it. Then place colors shapes on top with varying opacity and transparencies blends. Overlay, multiply, darken etc. Letting the textured paper show through may give the illusion want. Here's a link to my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzxv81nso2vx0ai/shapes-for-experiment-TEST.ai)